# JS Scripts triggers Cart/Delete

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, magento-2.0

I want to know what JS file and where can I find the JS file that triggers the cart->delete. I'm using Magento 2.3 and upon searching I found a file in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/Helper/Cart.php` and it has the function `getDeletePostJson` which return the json_encode action and url. This action is located in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/controller/cart/delete.php` but I don't know which JS file calls this? and after calling this function what is the next step to this script? I'm trying to debug why upon deleting an item in the cart it's redirecting me back to the homepage eventhough I have a few more items in the cart

Answer (score 0):

Its knockout js binding there

```
<a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-cart-item': item_id, title:
 $t('Remove item')}" class="action delete" data-cart-item="74398" 
title="Remove item">    
<span data-bind="i18n: 'Remove'">Remove</span></a>
```

and in minicart vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\shopping-cart.js

```
        $(document).on('ajax:removeFromCart', $.proxy(function () {
            reload = true;
            $('div.block.block-minicart').on('dropdowndialogclose', $.proxy(function () {
                if (reload === true) {
                    location.reload();
                    reload = false;
                }
                $('div.block.block-minicart').off('dropdowndialogclose');
            }));
        }, this));
```

and in checkout  vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\sidebar.js

```
events['click ' + this.options.button.remove] =  function (event) {
```